# Strip closing php tag using perl regex

Tags: php, regex, perl, tags

I have php file, and I want to remove closing tag (?>), but only if it is last closing tag and there is nothing after.

```
<?php
  //some code
?>
<?php
  //some other code
?> // <- this and only this should be removed
```

I have tried pattern 's/(\s*\?>\s*)$//s' and several of its mutations, but with no success: they remove all occurrences of ?>, breaking the code, and I don't know how to match EOF.

(Yes, I know a workaround: using e.g. `tail -1` to check only last line of file, but it would complicate my whole code-formatting script, so if the problem can be resolved with properly constructed regex, it would be great.)

Comment: Your regex should work - but only if you read the entire file content into one variable - and then parse it.  If you use something like `perl -p -i -e 's/(\s*\?>\s*)$//' filename.php`, then each line is processed one at a time.  Obviously, this will strip all occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now had a chance to test it.  Reading all file does work.  This perl code worked for me:

```
local $/;
open FH, "<", "tmp.php";
$var = <FH>;
print "$var\n\n";
close FH;
$var =~ s/(\s*\?>\s*)$//s;
print "$var\n";
```

on the following php code:

```
<?php
//some code
?>
<?php
//some other code
?>
```

Comment: It works: `perl -pi -w -0777 -e 's/(\s*\?>\s*)$/;/s' file.php` (argument -0777 for one-liner causes reading file as one string). Additionally, I have found that replacing ?> by empty string may cause syntax errors e.g. for such line: `<?php echo 'a' ?>. Replacing with ';' is safe. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's break this down.

You want to match '?>', so we'll start with `('?>')`, but since '?' has special meaning in regex, we need to escape it: `('\?>')`.

We don't care about what's before the closing tag, but we want to make sure nothing (except whitespace) is after it. You were pretty much on the money with this: we need `\s` and `$`. I'd do it like this:

```
('\?>')\s*$
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: `\w` is a word character, not whitespace. You want `\s`.